# Crystal Reports - Command Line CRExport.exe Odd Formula Error

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I built a report in crystal reports (version 11.5.12.1838 - yes it's old, but I have no ability to upgrade it, it comes with the software we use for cash reporting).

I have this formula:

```
    if (DateTime({@Date1}) = Datetime({rpcRGHL5DayBalanceView;1.1date}))
    then
        {rpcRGHL5DayBalanceView;1.1}
    else
        999999999999.99
```

The report runs and exports fine within crystal as well as the application we use.  However, when using CrExport.exe (free command line tool) the report fails to generate and provides this error.

```
    Error : A string is required here. Details: errorKind Error in File RGHL-5DayBalanceView {25B5C1DE-4C71-4A2D-816E-165F95A6B03B}.rpt:
    Error in formula  Balance1: 
    'if (DateTime({@Date1}) = Datetime({rpcRGHL5DayBalanceView;1.1date}))
    then ' A string is required here. Details: errorKind
```

This seems to happen when the parameter I pass in via the command line differs from the stored value on the report.  If I pass in the same value, the report generates, but the data is not updated.  The data that was saved on the report is what I get.

I use this CrExport.exe with several other reports with no problem.  Not sure if it's a bug in the command line tool or not.

Also, if I change the values from numeric to text via this code.

```
    if (DateTime({@Date1}) = Datetime({rpcRGHL5DayBalanceView;1.1date})) 
    then
        ToText({rpcRGHL5DayBalanceView;1.1},0)
    else
        ToText(999999999999.99)
```

Then I get this error from the command line program.

```
    Error : Too many arguments have been given to this function. Details: errorKind
    Error in File RGHL-5DayBalanceView {98633D00-5B70-4B7D-839C-1D0CEB359AE9}.rpt:
    Error in formula  Balance1: 'if (DateTime({@Date1}) = Datetime({rpcRGHL5DayBalanceView;1.1date})) then
    'Too many arguments have been given to this function.
    Details: errorKind
```

Any help is much appreciated. Let me know if more information is needed and I will do what I can to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
if (DateTime(CStr({@Date1})) = Datetime({rpcRGHL5DayBalanceView;1.1date})) 
then
    ToText(CStr({rpcRGHL5DayBalanceView;1.1}),0)
else
    ToText(999999999999.99)
```

Comment: Hmm, if you look further down you can see that I did indeed try that.  I then started to get a different error.  See at the end.

Comment: What is the datatype ofr pcRGHL5DayBalanceView